# just_audio can not play local asset audio

Tags: just-audio

Problem:

```
await _player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse("asset:///assets/audios/audio.mp3")));
```

I am running just_audio on flutterflow, but the online test doesn't work, I also tried download the apk and run from an android emulator without luck, too.

Does anyone know how to load local asset files from just_play? or is there other know audioplayer that work with local assets files.

Things I tried:
If I put "http://...mp3" the player will work. So, there is something odd with how the player handle the asset path.

I also double checked the pubspec.yaml the assets path is correct.
assets:

- assets/audios/

Comment: Does the official example with assets work? i.e. the one in just_audio/just_audio/example/lib/example_playlist.dart? And on what platform are you testing? And can you copy and paste the relevant code from your `pubspec.yaml`?